# Combine redirect to naked domain and point existing content to /blog

Tags: domains, htaccess, wordpress

I think the .htaccess setup for this ought to be fairly straightforward, but I'm having a hard time with it for some reason. I've just completed the migration of a WordPress single site installation to a MultiSite setup, and everything went swimmingly. Now, though, I need to redirect all the original blog posts to `/blog/<post>` (because WordPress enforces that on MultiSite).

I also recently migrated everything to the naked domain. This in and of itself wasn't a problem – until I added in the `/blog/` component.

Here is what I have for the naked domain redirect (which, as noted, works fine):

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.(.*)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://%1/$1 [R=301,L]
```

I've tried a number of things for the `/blog/` redirect, but it's continuing to throw me. It seems like it should be fairly easy with `RedirectMatch`:

```
RedirectMatch 301 ^/(.*/?)$ http://<my-site>/blog/$1
```

The problem, of course, is that this expression then captures `/blog/` and promptly heads off to `/blog/blog/blog/...`

I run into the same problem using another `RewriteCond`/`RewriteRule` pair, and when I tried to work around it like this:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(?:(www\.))?(.*)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(?<!(blog/))(.*)$ http://%1/blog/$1 [R=301,L]
```

The result was a redirect loop (I'm not seeing what's causing it, but my head is obviously not processing the regexes correctly this morning).

It seems to me like `RedirectMatch` is the way to go anyway; I just need to make sure not to capture `/blog/` itself.

**Edit:** I totally forgot about the `!` part of the rule; should I simply be starting that `RewriteMatch` with `!^blog`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could just do this:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/blog
RewriteRule ^(/?)(.*) /blog/$2 [L,R=301]
```

then anything that doesnt have a `/blog` in it will be rewritten to have the `/blog` in it.

(referenced from https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4844069/htaccess-rewritebase)

Comment: That looks like it would indeed probably work. I'll have to try it out sometime. (On the site I originally needed this for, I got around it another way, by getting rid of the `/blog` component entirely—something not easy but ultimately doable in the WordPress back end).

Comment: thanks, I didnt actually test it, but it should work :D